# Order By NewID()

Tags: sql, database

I have a quick question and below is my sample query:

```
    select 
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY diff ORDER BY NEWID())
        , Account, Ticker, Client, Diff, Allocation 
    from @diffAdj 
    where 
        Account = @Account 
        and Ticker = @Ticker
        and RemainingShares - isnull(Allocation, 0) > 0
    order by NEWID()
```

Just want to ask a question on the NEWID(). The NEWID is also used to get the row_Number partitioned, which should be executed before order by. So is my understanding as below correct:

As of each row looped, a newid is generated and stored in the new column created
This newid will be used to sort rows to generate row_number
The same new_id column will be used to sort rows in the order stage, or will it discard the newid from previous step and loop through each row and generate the newid column again, and sort it again usingthe new column.

I'm a very very very beginner in sql, appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: Your query, as written, does not really use the row number value for anything.  Why are you calling `ROW_NUMBER` ?

Comment: NEWID()  within ROW_NUMBER() and in the ORDER BY clause of the SELECT are not related.

Comment: @Serg So does that mean, there will be two newid column generated?

Comment: Yes, every NEWID() appearance in a query is executed at every row. NEWID() is a [nondetermenistic function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-ver16), so DB engine must not cache it values any way.

Comment: Welcome! As long as you follow the guidance in ["What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/11107541), then [you don't need to tell us that you are new to `X`](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296391/11107541).